# npm install does not modify the package.json in react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, package.json

I just created React App by "npx create-react-app", and then when I do "npm install redux" or "npm install --save-dev redux" or "npm install --save redux" - it just does not modify the package.json

I tried the same thing with "react-redux", "react-thunk"... And still... The package.json remains the same.

I do not know how to fix this.
Please, help.

```
  "name": "basic_redux_setup",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are on the right directory while executing the NPM scripts, which must be the same directory where the `package.json` file is located.